# Angular > 13 compile feature alternative

Tags: angular

for the needs of a project I have to dynamically load html data from db (which using angular components)
I can at the moment with angular 13 use the compiler for this.
however the compiler will be removed in V16.

So my question is what to replace this compiler with?

https://angular.io/api/core/Compiler

example :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y1zhwo-rl8yns

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned before in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52531995/bundling-angular-project-without-compiling):

> You can't really bundle your code without building it.

As such you can't remove the compiler from the Angular framework. Furthermore the compiler won't be removed in V16.

No need to replace the compiler due to *removal* of the compiler.

Comment: hello, 

Thanks for your feedback.
This is currently an angularjs project that I need to migrate to angular, and I can't change how it works.
currently i have working code with angular and compiler feature, it's work with my external html.
but the compiler is deprecated :( and this page announces the removing in v16 without indicating an alternative 

[link](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#jit-api-changes)

Comment: The use of @angular/core symbol Compiler is just going to be deprecated, not the ngc itself. [Docs](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#jit-api-changes): With Ivy, JIT compilation takes place implicitly if the Component, NgModule, etc have not already been AOT compiled.

Comment: who says obsolete, says delete.
Angular announces the removal of this API in v16. I am therefore looking for an alternative solution to my needs. that is to say, I repeat, load html containing component tags from an external source.
I cannot compile this html with the project.

Comment: We are misunderstanding the issue here together. Could you maybe include some reproducible code into your question?

Comment: i update the init message with an example